# .NET Core - SQL exception while building docker compose

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a simple web API application in .net core with SQL Server database and It works locally as well without docker. I have windows 10 Home edition and couldn't use docker directly and I have to use VirtualBox to using docker.

**Appsettings**

```
"DatabaseConfig": {
    "Server": "db",
    "Port": "1433",
    "Database": "CoreApiDatabase",
    "User": "sa",
    "Password": "Sae!d209sA"
  }
```

migration and seed the database in Configure method in startup.cs

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CoreApiDatabase.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./CoreApiDatabase.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "CoreApiDatabase.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CoreApiDatabase.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreApiDatabase.dll"]
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "Sae!d209sA"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  core-api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and finally, when running command *docker-compose up* I get this error while executing and doing migrations.

[image]

Comment: `"DatabaseConfig": { "Server": "db" }` ... do you have another machine on your network called "db"? Shouldn't this be "localhost"?

Comment: db is the name of service in docker-compose that mention in many tutorials

Comment: Give a ty by replacing the connection string with ip instead of hostname. Wondering if it the DB is reachable by the name.